# EditorTemplate for TemplateColumn in XamGrid not working

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, infragistics, xamgrid

I have a XamGrid with two columns, `Name` and `Type`. Depending on `Type`, I want to have a different kind of column for `Name`, thus I'm using a `TemplateColumn`. In the data template I have a `ContentControl` with a default `ContentTemplate` and a `DataTrigger` that sets the `ContentTemplate` to a different column style if `Type` is a specific value.
I am setting alll four templates (`ItemTemplate`, `EditorTemplate`, `AddNewRowItemTemplate`, `AddNewRowEditorTemplate`) of the `TemplateColumn` to this data template.

`ItemTemplate`, `AddNewRowItemTemplate` and `AddNewRowEditorTemplate` work as intended, however `EditorTemplate` does not, see attached pictures:

[image: <code>ItemTemplate</code> and <code>AddNewRowItemTemplate</code>]

[image: <code>AddNewRowEditorTemplate</code>]

[image: <code>EditorTemplate</code>]

Here is my code:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml"
        Width="640" Height="480" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditorTemplate">
            <TextBox Width="64"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="BoolEditorTemplate">
            <CheckBox/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding }">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditorTemplate}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="bool">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BoolEditorTemplate}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ig:XamGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <ig:XamGrid.EditingSettings>
            <ig:EditingSettings AllowEditing="Row" />
        </ig:XamGrid.EditingSettings>
        <ig:XamGrid.AddNewRowSettings>
            <ig:AddNewRowSettings AllowAddNewRow="Top" />
        </ig:XamGrid.AddNewRowSettings>

        <ig:XamGrid.Columns>
            <ig:TemplateColumn Key="Name"
                               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}"
                               AddNewRowItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}"
                               EditorTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}"
                               AddNewRowEditorTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}"/>
            <ig:TextColumn Key="Type"/>
        </ig:XamGrid.Columns>
    </ig:XamGrid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
  public partial class MainWindow
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Data> DataCollection { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Data>
    {
      new Data { Name = "Foo", Type = "bool" },
      new Data { Name = "Bar", Type = "enum" }
    };
  }

  public class Data
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here on the infragistics forum](https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/109967/517357.aspx#517357), for this use case not only is an `EditorTemplate` needed, but also an `EditorStyle`.

```
<Style x:Key="EditorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditorTemplate}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="bool">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BoolEditorTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding }"
                    Style="{StaticResource EditorStyle}" />>
</DataTemplate>

[...]

<ig:TemplateColumn Key="Name"
                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}"
                   AddNewRowItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}"
                   EditorTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}"
                   AddNewRowEditorTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}"
                   EditorStyle="{StaticResource EditorStyle}" />
```